# SED statement to replace variable inside Shell Script

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I've created a bash script that gets an IP Address as variable `${MYSQL_SERVER_IP}`. I then want to pass it in a sed to replace the previous IP address in a settings.py file. Here is the closest I have gotten to a sed statement that actually runs without error:

```
export MYSQL_SERVER_IP= '172.19.0.2'
sed -i -e '/DB_HOST =/c\DB_HOST = os.getenv( '\''IP'\'', '\''${MYSQL_SERVER_IP}'\'')\' Flask-URL-Shortener/settings.py
```

The problem is that the script doesn't replace the variable with the value of the variable.

In the file before running the script:

```
DB_HOST = os.getenv( 'IP', '172.31.0.2')
```

Currently the output I get is wrong:

```
DB_HOST = os.getenv( 'IP', '${MYSQL_SERVER_IP}')
```

as I would like to obtain the following output:

```
DB_HOST = os.getenv( 'IP', '172.19.0.2')
```

This sed statement is the last line of code I need to fix to make my program work the way I want it to.

Comment: I see that you have included in your question the current output and the desired output; can you please also include **in the question** the corresponding input?

Comment: The pattern `/\DB_HOST =\**/` matches `DB_HOST =` followed by zero or more `*`; is this your intention? (By the way it works just because `\D` is not special, so `\` is actually ineffective.)

Comment: @oguzismail When I try quoting my variable, it just puts the quotes in the setting.py file, no matter what I do, it does not replace the variable with the value of the variable

Comment: Please, provide an example, few lines **input file**.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis I fixed the asterisk part, but its not what I need. Main thing is that the variable is not being replaced by its value no matter what I do

Comment: My understanding is that `DB_HOST = os.getenv( 'IP', '${MYSQL_SERVER_IP}')` is what you **_currently get_** upon using your broken command (because you wrote _Current replacement_), and that `DB_HOST = os.getenv( 'IP', '172.19.0.2')` is what you **_want to get_** (because you wrote _Desired_). @WilliamPursell, in his answer, assumes that `DB_HOST = os.getenv( 'IP', '${MYSQL_SERVER_IP}')` is what you have in your `settings.py` file **_before_** editing it. Can you please clarify this? Besides, as I already wrote in a comment, please stop writing code in the comments and edit your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment, it seems like you need the following command

```
sed '/DB_HOST/s/[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}/'"$MYSQL_SERVER_IP"'/' yourfile
```

where the substitution command `s` is applied only to the lines matching the `DB_HOST` pattern (you can make it more complicated, e.g. `/DB_HOST *= */`, to match `DB_HOST` followed by `=`, the latter preceded and followed by zero or more spaces); the regexp of the `s` command contains 4 expressions matching between 1 and 3 digits (`[0-9]\{1,3\}`), interspersed with literal dots `\.`.

**Original answer**

Please, if the next three lines do not describe your case, leave a comment and clarify.

Let's say `myShortFile` contains only this line (since it is a simple text file, all characters, `$` included, are literal):

```
IP = $MYIP
```

Then, if you run such a `bash` script:

```
#!/bin/bash
MYIP="172.19.0.2"
sed 's/$MYIP/'"$MYIP"'/' myShortFile
```

you will get

```
IP = 172.19.0.2
```

The reason is that in the string concatenation `'…'"…"'…'`, the first and the third parts (`'s/$MYIP/'` and `/`) are interpreted literally by `bash`, since they are enclosed in single quotes (`'`), whereas the `$MYSIP` in the middle piece `"$MYIP"` is expanded, since it is in between double quotes (`"`). The result is that `bash` will execute the command

```
sed 's/$MYIP/172.19.0.2/' myShortFile
```

which substitutes `$MYIP` in `myShortFile` with `172.19.0.2` and prints the resulting output to screen.

Comment: thanks, but the file does not have any variables. I added how the file looks before running. The IP address in the file and in the variable are going to be different every run

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204273/discussion-between-yash-narang-and-enrico-maria-de-angelis).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you want to be using `c` here.   Just do:

```
sed -e '/DB_HOST\s*=/s/${MYSQL_SERVER_IP}/'"${MYSQL_SERVER_IP}"/
```

You can limit the replacement to the line containig `DB_HOST =`, but you don't need to try to do anything with that text in the replacement.  Only replace the part that needs to be changed.  Note that this will fail if MYSQL_SERVER_IP contains forward slashes, so you'll want to validate the data.

Comment: Thanks, I tried:
sed -i -e '/DB_HOST\s*=/s/${MYSQL_SERVER_IP}/'"${MYSQL_SERVER_IP}"/ Flask-URL-Shortener/settings.py but I got back this: sed: -e expression #1, char 75: unterminated `s' command . Which is weird since char 75 is where the file is in the command

Comment: I also tried: sed -i -e '/DB_HOST\s*=/s/${MYSQL_SERVER_IP}/"${MYSQL_SERVER_IP}"/' Flask-URL-Shortener/settings.py

but all it does is replace "${MYSQL_SERVER_IP}" with ""${MYSQL_SERVER_IP}"" (with more double quotes). Also the file is not going to have ${MYSQL_SERVER_IP} inside of it. It's going to have an actual IP Address to replace